# Get text in a <div> and output

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, twitter

I'm building a section which uses the jQuery UI to allow users to drag words around on screen to create their own sentences, which they can then share on Twitter.

I'm wanting the text they create to be inputted into the Twitter text area when they click the 'Tweet' button.

I'm hoping that, with PHP or JS, there would be a way to output the text that's been moved into the div, then input it into the '&text=Text%20goes%20here' part of the Twitter code.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=SUYearbook&text=Text%20goes%20here" 
   class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-size="large" 
   data-related="username">Tweet #SUYearbook</a>
```

You can see the set up here if you need to understand anything further: http://goo.gl/s6CBD

To reiterate: Drag text into area, on pressing the Tweet button (or a 'finish' button), it adds the text contents to the Twitter code and then it's there in the tweet modal.

Comment: And what particular part are you having the problem with? And please don't obfuscate your urls (SO doesn't charge per-character, so full URLs are much appreciated). Could you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) for us to see what you're working with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way would be to add a class to the `span` of each word on drop into the area, and then loop through each `span` with the appropriate class. Something like this:

```
$(".twitter-hashtag-button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = $(".selectedWord").map(function() {
        return $(this).text();
    }).get().join(' ');
    window.location.assign("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?button_hashtag=SUYearbook&text=" + text)
});
```

Comment: problem with this approach is that you lose the ordering of words

Comment: You can easily write a sorter function to sort the spans by `offset().left`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, guys. Strangely, the above code doesn't seem to work even if I apply a class name myself to see if it includes it in the tweet.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to use the `droppable` plugin on your target div and use the accept event to add the word to the twitter link.